# Custom wagtail page model save method called twice

Tags: django, wagtail

In a Django+Wagtail project, I have a custom method which I call from the model `save()` method. It works - but everytime I save an instance via the wagtail admin interface, this method is called twice - why?

```
# models.py
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class ArticlePage(Page):

    def my_method(self):
        print('I will be printed twice on save...')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_method() 
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

By using `traceback.print_stack` as suggested by [Håken Lid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977847/h%c3%a5ken-lid) I've found out that the method is first called via

```
  File ".../.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py", line 336, in edit
    submitted_for_moderation=is_submitting,
  File ".../.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/core/models.py", line 653, in save_revision
    self.save(update_fields=update_fields)
```

and the second time via

```
  File ".../.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py", line 343, in edit
    revision.publish()
  File ".../.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/core/models.py", line 1498, in publish
    page.save()
```

But even with this information I'm not aware how to only trigger my method on the second save...

Env:
Django 2.0.4
Wagtail 2.0.1

Comment: You can use the standard library `traceback` to print a call stack in `my_method` to diagnose this. Presumably there's something going on in a parent class. https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint, I will update my question with this information.  Unfortunately I do not know how to step in this behavior.

Comment: Then you want a debugger. `pdb` works with django runserver. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: Perhaps this behavior is a bit wagtail specific. I wanted to get rid of a post_save signal and re-implement it in the model save method.

Comment: Maybe you can list all signals. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087730/is-there-a-way-to-list-django-signals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to do something on page publish, You can use the `page_published` signals as below:

```
    from django.dispatch import receiver
    from wagtail.core.signals import page_published
    @receiver(page_published)
    def do_stuff_on_page_published(instance, **kwargs):
        print('=======================',instance,kwargs)
```

In case of save, you can also check the `update_fields` argument in the `kwargs`:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('update_fields'):
            pass # save not called from publish
            # do_stuff_on_save()
        else:
            pass
            # do_stuff_on_publish()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For more info about wagtail signal code visit this [link](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/core/signals.py)
and this for the official docs
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.7/reference/signals.html

Comment: I've already done this via ``post_save`` signal  and it is working as expected, but I would like to swap the signal handling with a custom save method.

Comment: in this case you can go for  second code mention above if kwargs.get('update_fields'):

Comment: in case of publish, save call two, one by default with update_fields and other from post method without update_fields params

Comment: Thanks a lot @prakash, your second example worked like a charm.